# Qt, Android. Как сохранить состояние приложения перед выходом/завершением?

Tags: android, qt, qml

Как перехватить событие завершения QML приложения на Android?
Пробовал вызывать функцию сохранения в деструкторе `QObject`. Но на Android деструктор при завершении не вызывается.

```
ChartPlotter::~ChartPlotter(){

    Utilits::saveSettings();

}
```

Также пробовал сохранять параметры при потере фокуса главного окна в QML (подумал что таким образом можно определить не завершение, но хотя бы переход в background). Но при сворачивании приложения  -  обработчик смены фокуса тоже не вызывается.

```
onActiveChanged: {
            console.log('changed')

         }
```

Какова же вообще практика сохранения состояния в Qt приложении на Android?

Comment: я не программирую в qml, но в C++ всё завершающие действия по Cancel, Esc, "X" (кнопка в windows в углу) надо делать в QDialog::reject() если у вас главное окно QDialog

Comment: В мобильных программах завершение происходит не пойми когда, поэтому там надо сохранять состояние не по завершению, а при первой возможности

Comment: сохраняйте сразу когда нужно сохранить что-то, уже много раз на этом обжигался